# How can I treat strings in Excel as predefined numbers?

Tags: excel

So I'm trying to build a spreadsheet to keep track of my working hours. But to make it more "automated" I need additional features. One of them is being able to treat specific strings as numbers, and use them in a formula.

Lets say that I'm John in the following example. I have 160 hours in paid vacation left, and I have manage to build pretty large chunk of paid flex time. Normal working hours is between 8-17. If I come in at work at 7 and leave at 17, I get +1 flex hour.

If I want to use my flextime I can in this case type **-8**. And the formula in **I5** would be `=SUM(C4:G4)` to sum this week/month/year what ever. And the final result, this weeks usage subtracted with the total (**J5**) `=B6+I5`.

But, what if I want to use my vacation time? In this example I want **VT** to be equal to -8 hours as well, but subtracted from the vacation time total. Im using Excel version 16.27 on MacOs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The formula is : =COUNTIF(C4:G4,"VT")*8

Answer (score 0):

`I4` = `=COUNTIF(C4:G4,"VT")*-8`

`I5` = `=SUM(C4:G4)`

`J4` = `=B5+I4`

`J5` = `=B6+I5`